# OpenCV 4.7 camera calibration with ChAruCo markers

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2017, aruco

I have trouble setting up the camera calibration features with charuco markes.
I am using Win10 with VS217 and openCV 4.7 installed from the download. Genuinely, the code can use AruCo markers and set up the Charuco Board, but the calibration functions are missing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp> 

const std::string in_path = "E:/CameraCalibration/images_original/";
const std::string out_path = "E:/CameraCalibration/images_calibrated/";

int main(int argc, char\*\* argv) {

// Create a Charuco board with 6x9 squares and 20x20 pixel squares  
cv::aruco::Dictionary AruCoDict =
 cv::aruco::getPredefinedDictionary(cv::aruco::DICT_6X6_250); 
cv::aruco::CharucoBoard ChAruCoboard(cv::Size(5, 7), 0.04f, 0.02f, AruCoDict); 

// Create aruco marker detector  
cv::aruco::DetectorParameters detectorParams = cv::aruco::DetectorParameters(); 
cv::aruco::ArucoDetector detector(AruCoDict, detectorParams); 

// Define the camera calibration parameters  
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point2f>> allCharucoCorners; 
std::vector<std::vector<int>> allCharucoIds; 
std::vector<cv::Mat> allImages; 
cv::Size imageSize; 
cv::Mat cameraMatrix, distCoeffs; 
std::vector<cv::Mat> rvecs, tvecs; 

// Detect Charuco markers in each image and add them to the calibration data  
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) { 
    // Load the image  
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread(in_path + cv::format("image%d.bmp", i)); 
    std::cout << cv::format("image%d.bmp") << std::endl; 
    allImages.push_back(image); 

    // Detect markers in the image  
    std::vector<int> ids; 
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point2f>> corners, corners_rejected; 
    detector.detectMarkers(image, corners, ids, corners_rejected); 

    // Identify Charuco markers in the image  
    if (ids.size() > 0) { 
        std::vector<cv::Point2f> charucoCorners; 
        std::vector<int> charucoIds; 
        cv::aruco::interpolateCornersCharuco(corners, ids, image, &ChAruCoboard, 
 charucoCorners, charucoIds); 

        // Add the Charuco markers to the calibration data  
        if (charucoIds.size() > 0) { 
            allCharucoCorners.push_back(charucoCorners); 
            allCharucoIds.push_back(charucoIds); 
            imageSize = image.size(); 
        } 
    } 
} 
// Calibrate the camera using the Charuco markers  
double repError = cv::aruco::calibrateCameraCharuco(allCharucoCorners,
 allCharucoIds, imageSize, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, rvecs, tvecs,
calibrationFlags);

// Print the calibration results  
std::cout << "Camera matrix:\n" << cameraMatrix << "\n\n"; 
std::cout << "Distortion coefficients:\n" << distCoeffs << "\n\n"; 
std::cout << "Rotation vectors:\n";  
for (const auto& rvec : rvecs) { std::cout << rvec << "\n"; } std::cout << "\n\n"; 
std::cout << "Translation vectors:\n";     
for (const auto& tvec : tvecs) { std::cout << tvec << "\n"; } std::cout << "\n\n"; 
std::cout << "Reprojection error: " << repError << "\n"; 

return 0; 
}
```

for `cv::aruco::interpolateCornersCharuco` I get the error

`namespace "cv::aruco" has no member "interpolateCornersCharuco"`

and for `cv::aruco::calibrateCameraCharuco` the error

`namespace "cv::aruco" has no member "calibrateCameraCharuco"`

Help is much appreciated!

I tried OpenCV 4.0. Could not get it working either.

Comment: `#include <opencv2/aruco/charuco.hpp>` to be sure?

Comment: Thanks Christoph, there is no folder /aruco/ neither the charuco.hpp in a subfolder of the opencv4.7. The aruco contribution has been merged to objdetect which contains some aruco header files. (aruco_board.hpp, aruco_detector.hpp, aruco_dirctionary.hpp, charuco_detector.hpp, and other non-aruco related header files. Furthermore, the aruco_xx.hpp does not contain the functions that are causing my error. I assume they are simply not there.

Comment: opencv's aruco is a mess right now and will likely keep being a mess until someone from the outside steps in and fixes it. try the two headers given at the top of this page: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/d53/aruco_8hpp.html and also try the header given in this tutorial: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d5/dae/tutorial_aruco_detection.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Christoph, you guided me onto the right track. I went back to **OpenCV4.0**. While the marker detection has been implemented in the object detection, the functions for ChAruCo calibration are still in the aruco folder. Both (cv::aruco::interpolateCornersCharuco and cv::aruco::calibrateCameraCharuco) can made be available with #include "opencv2/aruco/charuco.hpp".
one further thing. Creating the pointer to the ChAruCoboard did not work for according to the tutorial. I changed the code to:

// Create a Charuco board

```
cv::aruco::Dictionary AruCoDict = cv::aruco::getPredefinedDictionary(cv::aruco::DICT_4X4_250);
```

// pointer to ChAruCoboard object

```
cv::Ptr<cv::aruco::CharucoBoard> ptrChAruCoboard = new cv::aruco::CharucoBoard(cv::Size(8, 6), 0.005f, 0.003f, AruCoDict);
```

Now it is working like a champ! cheers

Answer (score 1):

Following [this OpenCV tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/da/d13/tutorial_aruco_calibration.html) on camera calibration worked for me using OpenCV 4.7.0. Instead of using a `calibrateCamera` function specific to Charuco, it uses the general `calibrateCamera` function. One important detail omitted from the sample code is to initialize the `detector` object as a Charuco detector ([docs](https://docs.opencv.org/4.7.0/d9/df5/classcv_1_1aruco_1_1CharucoDetector.html)).

Answer (score 0):

To me [this python code](https://mecaruco2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks_rst/Aruco/sandbox/ludovic/aruco_calibration_rotation.html) began to work when I updated `opencv-contrib-python` to `4.7.0.72` and `opencv-python` to `4.7.0.72`.

Before this update, I got the same errors.